# Is there an equivalent to Ctrl-Shift-R in Safari/WebKit?

Tags: caching, safari, webkit

Something that would really reload the page or resource, ignoring whatever might be in cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari always reloads (ctrl+r) a page [ignoring whatever that might be in the cache](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=306244).

As Athena points out, iframes are cached. It's actually not the iframe content, but the *request* that's cached.

> In those cases, Safari caches the
>   page, and then no matter which link
>   you click, shows the iframe from the
>   last click BEFORE the refresh (or
>   back/forward). It's then stuck on that
>   content, and shows it for all links.

This is overcome by assigning [a different iframe id on each load](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150101):

> iframe.id = new Date().getTime();

Comment: IME, this may not always be true if you're dealing with iframes.

Comment: Swati: oh nice. I've seen someone run into that error before, and deduce through trial and error that adding an ID would fix it. But that has always felt magic-incantationish to me. This is the first time that I have seen an actual explanation.

Thanks!